# How can this program work even though it's missing a bunch of imports?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm learning Kivy and finding the examples that come with the installation quite useful.
BUT I stumbled on something that I can't for the life of me make sense of...

It's in the RecycleView example: basic_data.py
Nothing complicated here and I'm very comfortable navigating the code and making sense of it. I open it in Atom and it runs fine.

But then I notice the imports at the beginning of the file:

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
```

That's it! No mention of kivy.uix.recycleview or any other packages containing any of the other classes used in the program!

Here's the whole file:

Can someone explain to me what strange black magic is going on here? I'm sure I'm just being stupid.

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


kv = """
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    Label:
        text: root.value

<Test>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    rv: rv
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(108)
        padding: dp(8)
        spacing: dp(16)
        Button:
            text: 'Populate list'
            on_press: root.populate()
        Button:
            text: 'Sort list'
            on_press: root.sort()
        Button:
            text: 'Clear list'
            on_press: root.clear()
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(8)
            Button:
                text: 'Insert new item'
                on_press: root.insert(new_item_input.text)
            TextInput:
                id: new_item_input
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                hint_text: 'value'
                padding: dp(10), dp(10), 0, 0
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(8)
            Button:
                text: 'Update first item'
                on_press: root.update(update_item_input.text)
            TextInput:
                id: update_item_input
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                hint_text: 'new value'
                padding: dp(10), dp(10), 0, 0
        Button:
            text: 'Remove first item'
            on_press: root.remove()

    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
        bar_width: dp(10)
        viewclass: 'Row'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: dp(2)
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)


class Test(BoxLayout):

    def populate(self):
        self.rv.data = [{'value': ''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 6))}
                        for x in range(50)]

    def sort(self):
        self.rv.data = sorted(self.rv.data, key=lambda x: x['value'])

    def clear(self):
        self.rv.data = []

    def insert(self, value):
        self.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': value or 'default value'})

    def update(self, value):
        if self.rv.data:
            self.rv.data[0]['value'] = value or 'default new value'
            self.rv.refresh_from_data()

    def remove(self):
        if self.rv.data:
            self.rv.data.pop(0)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Those classes aren't in your code, exactly; they're inside a *string*. They will be imported by whatever is interpreting that string.

Comment: Really?!? Still feels like magic to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for [kivy.lang.Builder](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html#kivy.lang.builder.Builder) suggest that the other imports are handled by the string parser. For instance, the `root.sort()` call within the string is matched to the `root` object within Kivy's global context.

> The Builder is responsible for creating a Parser for parsing a kv file, merging the results into its internal rules, templates, etc.